# crear un boton para llamar skype desde un array nav en yii2

Tags: php, bootstrap, yii2

buenas tardes espero puedan ayudarme con este problemita tengo una app en `yii2` y necesito un boton `<a href="tel:+12300000000">WhatsApp 24/7 +12300000000 (Jose)</a>` que contenga ese link para poder usar las funciones de cuando abran la app en un movil o llamar desde skype en la pc, como sea. el problema esta es que estoy usando `yii2` y tengo este codigo en el `Main.php`

`

```
  echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-right '],
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'WhatsApp 24/7 +12300000000 (Jose)', 'url' => ['01245']],            
        ],
    ]);`
```

y ni idea de que mas hacer. de ante mano gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solucionado a esta linea sol le cambie`['label' => 'WhatsApp 24/7 +12300000000 (Jose)', 'url' => ['01245']]`

por

```
['label' => 'WhatsApp 24/7 +12300000000 (Jose)', 'url' => 'tel:01245']
```

ya que los corchetes hacen que se redirija a una direccion dentro de la carpeta `Site` de cualquier manera muchas gracias por el tiempo